# Woocommerce API - Products featured images

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using the Woocommerce API to save products into my store. The problem is that I can't set the featured image or main image to the product, they are all saved into the image gallery of the product but I can't find how to set that main image trough the API or if I have to make it work trough the Database... I don't want to go product by product setting that main image...

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved adding position => 0 to the selected featured image of the images array.

https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#http-request

Comment: Can you please be more precise. what do you mean by position => 0

Comment: images => [
   [
      'position' => 0,
      'src' => ...
   ]
]

Excuse me @Benjamin, add the position key to every image object .. the one with position = 0 will be the featured image

Comment: I did this and it worked. '{product.images[0].src}'